# PHP Associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an array as

```
$arrTest = array('val1','val2','val3','val4');
$arrTest['lastKey'] = 'Last Key';
foreach($arrTest as $key => $val) {
  if($key == 'lastKey') {
     echo "last found";
  }
}
```

The above code is not working. I have added associative element in the array. Could it be the reason?

Comment: "Not working" means what exactly - the last key is never found?

Comment: do you get any errors? I just ran your code and it echoed out... In fact it echoed twice... If you make the comparison operator check for identical you only get one echo as expected.... Though I'm not sure why. anyone care to elaborate?

Comment: I tried to run this code, and it writes "last found" twice. Really interesting.

Comment: down voted for not clear question

Comment: I am sorry for posting unclear Question. Actually it echos the "last found " twice for the first and last element i.e for 0 element also

Comment: downvoted for being a very bad way to iterate over an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your equality condition to check the type as well.

```
if($key === 'lastKey')
```

This is because PHP evaluates `' ' == 0` as true.

Answer (score 6):

Change `==` to `===` in:

```
if($key == 'lastKey')
```

Your existing code echos `last found` twice, once for key `0` and once for key `lastKey`.

Comparing integer `0` and string `'lastKey'` using `==` returns true !!

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> **String conversion to numbers**
>
> When a string is evaluated in a
>   numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> The string will be evaluated as a
>   float if it contains any of the
>   characters '.', 'e', or 'E'.
>   Otherwise, it will be evaluated as an
>   integer.
>
> The value is given by the initial
>   portion of the string. **If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this
>   will be the value used. Otherwise, the
>   value will be 0 (zero)**. Valid numeric
>   data is an optional sign, followed by
>   one or more digits (optionally
>   containing a decimal point), followed
>   by an optional exponent. The exponent
>   is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or
>   more digits.

Comment: Why comparison for 0 returns true?

Comment: @Umar: I've added the reason for this rather strange behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Use `===` to compare. Because when key `0` will be compared with string `lastKey`, string will be converted to integer and false result will be returned.
http://codepad.org/5QYIeL4f

```
$arrTest = array('val1','val2','val3','val4');
$arrTest['lastKey'] = 'Last Key';
foreach($arrTest as $key => $val) {
  if($key === 'lastKey') {
     echo "last found";
  }
}
```

Read more about differences: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: no doubt false will be returned for the comparison 0 but its displaying last found twice which means its returns true in case of 0 comparison

Comment: I mean `false result`, not just `false` as value :) Sorry for my broken English.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran your code, 'last found' was outputted twice.  'lastKey' is evaluated to 0 in PHP, so `if($key == 'lastKey')` actually matches twices: once for 0 and once for your special element.

Answer (score 0):

use the end() function to get the last key of an array and compare it in your if statement.

```
$arrTest = array('val1','val2','val3','val4');
$lastKey = end($arrTest);
foreach($arrTest as $key => $val) {
  if($val == $lastKey) {
     echo "last found";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine :
see it here : http://codepad.org/hfOFHMnc

However use "===" instead of "==" as you might encounter a bug when
comparing the string with 0 , and it will echo twice.

```
<?php

$arrTest = array('val1','val2','val3','val4');
$arrTest['lastKey'] = 'Last Key';
print_r($arrTest);

foreach($arrTest as $key => $val) {
  if($key == 'lastKey') {       // use === here
     echo "key = $key   :: last found \n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if an array key exists, simply use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists):

```
array_key_exists('lastKey', $arrTest)
```

You could also use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) but note that it returns *false* if the value associated to the key is `null`.